# How to execute API using curl on my Wordpress site from marketcheck.com?

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I am new to API's and i want to get data from marketcheck.com through API on my WordPress site for searching cars inventory. I also don't know where to write the API code whether in functions.php file or somewhere else. Below is the link provided by marketcheck.com for Car Search:

```
http://marketcheck-prod.apigee.net/v2/search/car/active?api_key={{api-key}}&year=2015&make=ford&host=marketcheck-prod.apigee.net
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNdRs.png)

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a complete set of functions to use instead of cURL for within WordPress environment.

You could either create a function within your functions.php to return your data in an array, or within your template, use the [wp_remote_get](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_get/) set of functions to get the BODY and json_decode.

```
$url = 'http://marketcheck-prod.apigee.net/v2/search/car/active?api_key={{api-key}}&year=2015&make=ford&host=marketcheck-prod.apigee.net';
$response = wp_remote_get($url);
$body = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($response), true);
```

then you'd loop through your $body results to retrieve the data.  It appears that you want to loop through $body->listings

```
foreach ($body->listings as $listing){
     // Do your loop magic here
     print_r($listing); // to review your loop data on screen
}
```